# moving code to modules in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, module

I have a small program that scans documents and reads a barcode (which is then split into different directories and a filename). This all works ok but I now need to expand the program a little. I need to add another couple of forms that do similar things so I have moved the code that does the work to the scanned image (i.e crop,rotate,getbarcode etc) into a module.

As soon as I do that I can`t get the code to do what it was doing.

For example the code I have to crop the image is as follows :

```
Public Sub Crop()

    Dim imageAttr1 As New ImageAttributes()
    imageAttr1.SetGamma(2.2F)
    bitmap1 = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(path & StrFileName & ".bmp")
    Try

        PicBitmap = bitmap1 'CType(Bitmap.FromStream(MyImage), Bitmap)
        OKTickets.ImgTicket.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        If bitmap1 IsNot Nothing Then
            bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
            OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image = bitmap1
        End If

        cropX = 2700
        cropY = 600
        cropWidth = 1200 'PictureBox1.Width
        cropHeight = 500 'PictureBox1.Height

        'a rectangle to set the location and size from the source image
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight)

                    Dim bit As Bitmap = New Bitmap(OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height)

        'create a new bitmap with the width/height values that were specified in the textboxes.
        cropBitmap = New Bitmap(cropWidth, cropHeight)

        'a new Graphics object that will draw on the cropBitmap
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)

        'draw the portion of the image that you supplied cropping values for.
        g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        g.DrawImage(cropBitmap, rect, 0, 0, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr1)
        'OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image = cropBitmap

        MsgBox("image done")

        'Dim rect As New Rectangle(250, 20, 200, 200)

    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check the path to the bitmap.")
    End Try

End Sub
```

If this is in the same class as the form then it does what it is supposed to do and crop the scanned image and display it in the picturebox(ImgTicket) on form1. If I move it to a module nothing is displayed in the picturebox. I have stepped through the code and it runs ok but just doesn't show the cropped image in the picturebox.

I haven`t used modules before so any beginner explanations would be helpful as all the things I`ve already read have me totally confused.

The code for the module is as follows :

```
Imports System.Drawing
```

Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Module ScanImage

```
Dim bitmap1 As Bitmap
Dim cropBitmap As Bitmap
Dim cropX As Integer
Dim cropY As Integer
Dim cropWidth As Integer
Dim cropHeight As Integer
Dim path As String = "C:\ProSys\Images\Test\Temp\"
Dim StrFileName As String = "1"
Dim PicBitmap As Bitmap

Public Sub Crop()

    Dim imageAttr1 As New ImageAttributes()
    imageAttr1.SetGamma(2.2F)
    bitmap1 = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(path & StrFileName & ".bmp")
    Try

        PicBitmap = bitmap1 'CType(Bitmap.FromStream(MyImage), Bitmap)
        OKTickets.ImgTicket.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        If bitmap1 IsNot Nothing Then
            bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
            OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image = bitmap1
        End If

        cropX = 2700
        cropY = 600
        cropWidth = 1200 'PictureBox1.Width
        cropHeight = 500 'PictureBox1.Height

        'a rectangle to set the location and size from the source image
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight)

        Dim bit As Bitmap = New Bitmap(OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height)

        'create a new bitmap with the width/height values that were specified.
        cropBitmap = New Bitmap(cropWidth, cropHeight)

        'a new Graphics object that will draw on the cropBitmap
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)

        'draw the portion of the image that you supplied cropping values for.
        g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        g.DrawImage(cropBitmap, rect, 0, 0, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr1)
        OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image = cropBitmap

    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check the path to the bitmap.")
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: can you post the code with your Module ? because I don;t understand why you moved from Form (class) to module .. anf can you check in Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)  cropBitmap what Widht and Height has .. ? maybe you foget some size varibale and image is 0 px

Comment: edited my question to include the module code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, I see you have a lot of things declared on a modular level, and I don't really see a point to this for such a simple end function.

Consider a simpler, more-reusable way such as this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Module Module1
    Public Function CropBitmap(bm As Bitmap, cropRect As Rectangle) As Image
        Dim CropImage As New Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
            g.DrawImage(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using
        Return CropImage
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: How would I call this function for an image that is scanned and saved from the main form.

Comment: croppedimg = Cropbitmap(sourceImg,CropRect)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, comment some lines and use Paul Ishak's Function:

```
Dim bitmap1 As Bitmap
Dim cropBitmap As Bitmap
Dim cropX As Integer
Dim cropY As Integer
Dim cropWidth As Integer
Dim cropHeight As Integer
Dim path As String = "C:\ProSys\Images\Test\Temp\"
Dim StrFileName As String = "1"
Dim PicBitmap As Bitmap

Public Sub Crop()

Dim imageAttr1 As New ImageAttributes()
imageAttr1.SetGamma(2.2F)
bitmap1 = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(path & StrFileName & ".bmp")
Try

    PicBitmap = bitmap1 'CType(Bitmap.FromStream(MyImage), Bitmap)
    OKTickets.ImgTicket.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
    If bitmap1 IsNot Nothing Then
        bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
        OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image = bitmap1
    End If

    cropX = 2700
    cropY = 600
    cropWidth = 1200 'PictureBox1.Width
    cropHeight = 500 'PictureBox1.Height

    'a rectangle to set the location and size from the source image
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight)

    'Dim bit As Bitmap = New Bitmap(OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height)

    'create a new bitmap with the width/height values that were specified.
    'cropBitmap = New Bitmap(cropWidth, cropHeight)

    'a new Graphics object that will draw on the cropBitmap
    'Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)

    'draw the portion of the image that you supplied cropping values for.
    'g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    'g.DrawImage(cropBitmap, rect, 0, 0, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Width, OKTickets.ImgTicket.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr1)
    OKTickets.ImgTicket.Image = cropBitmap(bitmap1, rect)

Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check the path to the bitmap.")
End Try

End Sub
```